# What's the simplest way to wrap up an existing Windows with a Linux host?

Tags: debian, windows, virtual-machine

I have a laptop with an existing Windows 10 installation. I want to install Linux along with it on the same drive and have it as my first OS while still being able to operate on Win10 through virtualisation.

I am familiar with VirtualBox, but now I've come to learn a bit about Xen  and KVM for the first time. Using VirtualBox would be the easiest way to go for me, were I to install Windows anew. But it's already there, and I'd rather not reinstall it on the host.

As for the host Linux, I'm planning to go with the new Debian 9 or possibly Ubuntu 16.04.

There's one more factor to include in the equation. The virtualisation switches on the laptop are disabled in BIOS at the moment and I'm unable to change this. The Windows that's there is 64 bit. I first tried to install Linux as a guest on Windows and found out about the BIOS lock when I could only install 32bit Linux images. I guess I've met a solution somewhere with KVM being able to somehow fool the guest about the processor setup and have it run 64 bit. I may be wrong though.

The performance is not of the utmost import here. I want the maximum simplicity of installation and maintenance later on. And just to clarify, it would be desirable to be able to run Windows on its own without hipervision, so it needs to retain its own boot loader line in the new configuration.

Comment: concerning the reopen: the main problem (addressed in the answer) is off topic, and since simple is in the eye of the beholder (and subject to change) it is not a significant limiting factor to the very broad subject of virtualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this until you can resolve the show-stopper, "*The virtualisation switches on the laptop are disabled in BIOS at the moment and I'm unable to change this*".

Once this is done you can use KVM (and possibly other virtualisation systems) to run Windows in a VM even though it's still installed in physical partitions on your drive. (Whether Windows will cope with you changing the effective hardware underneath it is not something I can confirm. You may find your Windows OS licence gets locked out because you've changed "too much" hardware at once. Be warned.)